# Is it valid to give an answer a bounty but not mark it as the right answer?

Tags: discussion, bounty, accepted-answer

I had a few answers lately for questions with bounties on them.

In these cases, the users gave me the bounty but didn't mark an answer as the right answer:

- [AngularJS - Reload page 5 seconds once progress bar is 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56411431/angularjs-reload-page-5-seconds-once-progress-bar-is-100/56445521#56445521)
- [Trying to figure a way to read all the files in a directory, re-create and write files programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369668/trying-to-figure-a-way-to-read-all-the-files-in-a-directory-re-create-and-write/56459901#56459901)

I found this decoupling weird. I thought that bounties are given when an answer is selected as the right answer. Can someone mark one question as the right one and give the bounty to another? Shouldn't the bounty be given when the user selects an answer as correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For both these questions, the bounty was auto-awarded, and not assigned by the author of the question.

It's reasonable to assume the author didn't award the bounty because even though the answer was upvoted, it didn't suffice in their opinion. If that's the case, it's certainly right to not accept the answer, even though it got a part of the bounty automatically.

Comment: But shouldn't then the user not get the bounty? I know I'm risking getting the bounty awards removed ;-), but doesn't that makes sense that the bounty should not be given if the user didn't found any answer sufficient?

Comment: Well, the community thinks the answer holds value and has expressed that by upvoting it, so the compromise was made to award half the bounty to the most upvoted answer if the one placing the bounty does not award it at all, to not risk excellent answers not getting the bounty if the one placing it abandons the question. As for all compromises, it has its up- and downsides. You can read the [help section on bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) for more details about when it's auto-awarded.

Comment: @Thatkookooguy you've been around for a while, surely you have already felt the pang of annoyance that so many questions you interact with just get abandoned without a single response, not even the memed "thanks I fixed it"? You can't trust people to do the right thing, many don't for varying reasons. You made the effort to answer, people like it, the answer deserves what it got.